# Mule - Catch Exception strategy isn't being called for specified exception

Tags: exception, error-handling, mule, esb

I'm trying to implement an error handling strategy for my Mule application which is writing data to a database. I have the following example of an exception that is thrown when trying to insert a record that has a duplicate identifier:

```
ERROR 2014-03-17 16:02:15,990 [[processes].inputConnector.receiver.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=jdbc://insertRecord, connector=JdbcConnector
{
  name=dbQueries
  lifecycle=start
  this=4c6f44a0
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=false
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[jdbc]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.jdbc.insertRecord', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={queryTimeout=-1}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: HashMap
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL140317160209540' defined on 'TESTTABLE'. (org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException)
  org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException:-1 (null)
2. The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL140317160209540' defined on 'TESTTABLE'.(SQL Code: 30000, SQL State: + 23505) (org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedSQLException)
  org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory:-1 (null)
3. The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL140317160209540' defined on 'TESTTABLE'.(SQL Code: 30000, SQL State: + 23505) (java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException)
  org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40:-1 (null)
4. The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL140317160209540' defined on 'TESTTABLE'. Query: INSERT INTO TestTable (Id, Quantity) VALUES (?, ?) Parameters: [261000153085, 7](SQL Code: 30000, SQL State: + 23505) (java.sql.SQLException)
  org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner:540 (null)
5. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=jdbc://insertRecord, connector=JdbcConnector
{
  name=dbQueries
  lifecycle=start
  this=4c6f44a0
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=false
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[jdbc]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.jdbc.insertRecord', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={queryTimeout=-1}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: HashMap (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher:109 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
ERROR 23505: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL140317160209540' defined on 'TESTTABLE'.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.IndexChanger.insertAndCheckDups(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.IndexChanger.doInsert(Unknown Source)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

I've got a Choice Exception strategy defined to deal with different exceptions and have used the following to handle the case outlined:

```
<catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causeMatches(org.apache.derby.*)]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">         
     <logger level="ERROR" message="Database error." doc:name="Logger"/>
</catch-exception-strategy>
```

However, the exception always gets routed to the default strategy and not the catch strategy defined above. I'm assuming this is an issue with my 'when' expression, I'm just not sure how to resolve it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please provide your full flow config. That might provide some extra clues.

Comment: @user1760178, I think the error lies in the 'when' expression I've defined. I have another which works fine: `<catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">         
             <logger level="ERROR" message="Transformation error." doc:name="Logger"/>
         </catch-exception-strategy>`

Answer (score 1):

This is a method which takes regular expression as the argument.

Try the folliwing one and it should work.

```
<catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causeMatches('org.?apache.?derby.?.*')]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">         
     <logger level="ERROR" message="Database error." doc:name="Logger"/>
</catch-exception-strategy>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, this still didn't work and the default exception strategy was called. Could I instead use `exception.causedBy(...)` with some other expression? I've tried `exception.causedBy(org.apache.derby)` with no luck...

Comment: In order to use regular expression kind of scenarios only exception.causeMatches will work. One more option would be to use the exception.causedBy() with the root or parent exception of all the Derby Exceptions you are expecting.

Comment: The solution I have provided here is what I have tested and it worked. Did you try and print the Exception object caught in the exception strategy and what is its exact class.

Comment: How would I go about printing the exception object?

Comment: Use logger and #[exception] in your default exception strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You need a String argument for method causeMatches:

http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html

Try using quotes: exception.causeMatches('org.apache.derby.*')

Comment: This still didn't work, perhaps it's to do with there being multiple items in the exception stack?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint violated
```

This can be handled with the help of the using a condition in the code as shown using important keywords in the error as shown:

```
catch (SQLException e) { 
    if(e.getMessage().contains("unique constraint")) {        
        System.out.println("PID Repeated. Enter a different PID");
    } 
    return -1; 
}
```